# Difference between c() and append()

Tags: r, function

What is the difference between using `c()` and `append()`? Is there any?

```
> c(      rep(0,5), rep(3,2) )
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 3 3

> append( rep(0,5), rep(3,2) )
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 3 3
```

Comment: `c` is also a primitive with several S3 methods (see `methods("c")`)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The way you've used it doesn't show difference between `c` and `append`. `append` is different in the sense that it allows for values to be inserted into a vector *after a certain position*.

Example:

```
x <- c(10,8,20)
c(x, 6) # always adds to the end
# [1] 10 8 20 6
append(x, 6, after = 2)
# [1] 10  8  6 20
```

If you type `append` in R terminal, you'll see that it uses `c()` to append values.

```
# append function
function (x, values, after = length(x)) 
{
    lengx <- length(x)
    if (!after) 
        c(values, x)
    # by default after = length(x) which just calls a c(x, values)
    else if (after >= lengx) 
        c(x, values)
    else c(x[1L:after], values, x[(after + 1L):lengx])
}
```

You can see (the commented part) that by default (if you don't set `after=` as in your example), it simply returns `c(x, values)`. `c` is a more generic function that can concatenate values to `vectors` or `lists`.